# How can I check a process regarding to availability?

Tags: loops, process, delegates, menuitem

How can I check a process regarding to availability?

Example: `MenuItem.Click += delegate { Process.Start(Verknüpfung[1 + j]); };`

"Verknüpfung[1 + j]" is a process I read from a list (in a loop). It works fine. Unfortunately, there is a process, that cannot be run, because it does not exist.

Example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\Version9\TeamViewer.exe`

TeamViewer is not installed, so it cannot be run. How do I catch these processes regarding to availability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if their executable exists by using `System.IO.File.Exists` or you can insert `Process.Start` into `try...catch` clause. An exception will be thrown when trying to launch program which doesn't exist.

Comment: Oh damn, so easy... maybe TOO easy. The try catch clause fixed my problem. Thanks.